# JBang on OpenJ9

Tags: java, ibm-jdk, openj9

I'm trying to run the latest JBang v0.102.0 on Eclipse/IBM JDK, but I get this error.
Any suggestions?

```
C:\bin\jbang\bin>java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.5.0 (build 17.0.5+8)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 17.0.5.0 (build openj9-0.35.0, JRE 17 Windows 11 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20221018_298 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - e04a7f6c1
OMR      - 85a21674f
JCL      - 32d2c409a33 based on jdk-17.0.5+8)

C:\bin\jbang\bin>jbang.cmd
Errore: LinkageError durante il caricamento della classe principale dev.jbang.Main
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: jdk/internal/loader/URLClassPath$JarLoader.csu
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide more details about your environment; using the same VM works for me:

```
C>java --version openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18 IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition 17.0.5.0 (build 17.0.5+8) Eclipse OpenJ9 VM 17.0.5.0 (build openj9-0.35.0, JRE 17 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20221018_298 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) OpenJ9   - e04a7f6c1 OMR     
- 85a21674f JCL      - 32d2c409a33 based on jdk-17.0.5+8)

C>dir  Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume Serial Number is 980D-DE8B

 Directory of C:\cygwin\home\keithc\jbang-0.102.0\bin

80/02/01  00:00    <DIR>          . 80/02/01  00:00    <DIR>          .. 80/02/01  00:00             7,495 jbang 80/02/01  00:00             3,115 jbang.cmd 80/02/01  00:00         5,810,175 jbang.jar 80/02/01  00:00             7,737 jbang.ps1
               4 File(s)      5,828,522 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  269,905,985,536 bytes free

C>jbang.cmd --version
0.102.0
```

It also works with a jar I built from source:

```
C>java -cp jbang.jar dev.jbang.Main --version
0.102.0.7
```

Comment: The version command doesn't execute successfully either:
`C:\bin\jbang\bin>java -cp jbang.jar dev.jbang.Main --version
Errore: LinkageError durante il caricamento della classe principale dev.jbang.Main
        java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: jdk/internal/loader/URLClassPath$JarLoader.csu`
Anyway, I have downloaded the zip from https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang/releases/tag/v0.102.0